# Can't boot from Live CD nor Pendrive

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to install Windows 8 along side it. But I can't boot from any live CD or pendrive. My laptop goes into network boot and says- insert proper boot device and press any key.

My laptop is Asus x54c.

Answer (score 3):

This is an isse with your BIOS/EFI boot settings. Make sure you have the right settings (CD-Drive/Pendrivve before Network-boot/HDD).

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after you restart your laptop, press DEL or F12 or F2 depending upon your laptop model to ender into BIOS settings.
Using Arrow keys, select Boot options, and make sure that the USB Disk is set to First Boot device and CD Drive is set to Second Boot device.

Your internal hard disk should be the third on the priority list.
Then save changes (Press F10 to save and exit) and exit. This will restart your laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Very specific answer to your particular laptop, but which can be useful also for other laptops if you just find out the correct keys:

For everyone who ran into this same problem also:

1. Plug your USB-memory stick or CD drive into your notebook
2. Reboot your laptop
3. Press  straight after the first screen comes up which will get
   you into your BIOS
       You will see the USB stick as one of the boot options
       Remember: it speaks for itself that it must be a bootable stick  to be able to boot from it

In case you don't see your stick present after following above steps, you might try these
next steps out:

1. Press  straight after the first screen comes up which will get
   you into your BIOS
2. Go to the 'Boot' tab
3. In this 'Boot Settings'-screen, use your arrow buttons to move down to 'Boot Device Priority' and press .
4. (Double)check if you have [Removable Device] enabled as one of the Boot options.
5. If not, move down to the '3rd Boot Device' and press
6. Move down to 'Removable Device' and press
7. When it is set, press [F10] to save your settings and press  to confirm.

The notebook will reboot and when everything else is fine, you can pick the memory stick to boot from, using the  button after the (re)boot.

Answer (score 1):

**Your bios is booting from Hard drive before the cd .**

#### 1

You can choose the boot by typing F8 keyboard button in the starting.

#### 2

in the starting boot press delete button 
you can change this in the bios boot .
you have to make it boot from cd before the hdd .
next time share the bios version .
if you are running linux (ubuntu,fedora,...) use this command

```
sudo dmidecode -t 0
```

if you are running windows type in command :

```
sysinfo
```

if you are running mac os 
you will find it in :

```
'about this mac' => More Info
```

you will find the bios version
after you this google it & you will get how to change the boot

Comment: Your instructions are very specific, in reality the keys you need to press and what you need to do can vary widely between motherboard vendors